# Using Python to extract flood hazard info from National Flood Hazard Layer (NFHL) using any given lat/long point?

Tags: python, flood, nfhl

Can Python be used to extract flood hazard classifications from [National Flood Hazard Layer (NFHL) site](https://fema.maps.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=cbe088e7c8704464aa0fc34eb99e7f30) using any given lat/long point?

Specifically the following [seven classifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMquY.png):

- 1% Annual Chance Flood Hazard
- Regulatory Floodway
- Special Floodway
- Area of Undetermined Flood Hazard
- 0.2% Annual Chance Flood Hazard
- Future Conditions 1% Annual Chance Flood Hazard
- Area with Reduced Risk Due to Levee

[Flood Hazard Zones (28)](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/28) appears to contain these seven classifications.

Additional information:

[NFHL GIS Services user guide](https://www.fema.gov/media-library-data/20130726-1919-25045-5493/gis_services_user_guide.pdf)

[Definitions of FEMA Flood Zone Designations](http://snmapmod.snco.us/fmm/document/fema-flood-zone-definitions.pdf)

some notes:

`nfhl_layers = fiona.open(county_nfhl_file_path) nfhl_layer_1 = shape(nfhl_layers['geometry'] lat = 47.661694 long= -122.192574`

-- Given the lat/long, calculate the seven flood hazards for that point

This function returns true if that point is in the layer and false if it is not.

`def is_lat_long_in_nfhl_layer(lat, long, nfhl_layer): pass print is_lat_long_in_nfhl_layer(lat,long, nfhl_layer_1) def get_nfhl_predicates(lat,long): ...... return {"1%_annual_chance" : percent_chance_1, "0.2%_annual_chance": percent_chance_0_point_2,}`

Comment: What have you tried? When asking for Python coding help, it is expected that you provide your best effort to solve the problem.

Comment: I am a Python novice... some notes: `nfhl_layers = fiona.open(county_nfhl_file_path)
nfhl_layer_1 = shape(nfhl_layers['geometry']

lat = 47.661694
long= -122.192574`

-- GIven the lat/long, calculate the seven flood hazards for that point

This function returns true if that point is in the layer and false if it is not.
`def is_lat_long_in_nfhl_layer(lat, long, nfhl_layer):
pass

print is_lat_long_in_nfhl_layer(lat,long, nfhl_layer_1)

def get_nfhl_predicates(lat,long):
......
return {"1%_annual_chance" : percent_chance_1, "0.2%_annual_chance":
percent_chance_0_point_2,}`

Comment: Python can be used to do basically anything, seeing as it is Turing complete. Time to start learning it, as it will vastly enhance what you can do in GIS :-)